# Why is Backbone.js looking for the template before I render the view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js and I'm writing a small app. I decided to structure everything related to each resource (books, authors) in separate files (books.js, authors.js). Each file features four BBjs classes: a model, a collection, a model view and a collection view corresponding to the given resource. This was working fine when only one of this files was to be included.

Now I'm working on a screen that should show a book collection in a specific author page. I do not intend to render any of the author views, but only to use the author model. However, Backbone is failing with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined (underscore.js)` because it's looking for a template that's not present on this page.

My author view class looks like this:

```
app.AuthorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    template: _.template( $('#book-table-row-template').html() ),
    ...
    render: function(e) { ... }
});
```

The page does not feature any `#book-table-row-template` element (I guess that's what triggering the error) but I'm not even instantiating this view. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other more productive way to organize my backbone classes?

Comment: You are calling the `_.template` function right away. It doesn't wait for instantiation. And if there is no `#book-table-row-template`, jQuery will not find that either. If you want it to wait until instantiation, set `this.template` in your `initialize` method.

Comment: @kalley LOL you're right. Shame on me, I should've figured that out by myself. Thanks man. Post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `_.template` function right away. It doesn't wait for instantiation. And if there is no `#book-table-row-template`, jQuery will not find that either.

If you want it to wait until instantiation, set `this.template` in your `initialize` method, like so:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.template = _.template( $('#book-table-row-template').html() );
}
```